# ScriptResource.axd runtime error on line var f=($telerik.isIE)?document.createElement(<iframe name='"+this.get_id()+"'>")

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, iframe, telerik

This error occurs during runtime in the ScriptResource.axd which is my main issue as I cannot edit the code or I would have resolved it.
it occurs specifically on line

```
ScriptResource.axd runtime error on line var f=($telerik.isIE)?document.createElement(<iframe name='"+this.get_id()+"'>"):document.createElement("iframe");
```

I have added the custom code

```
 var $T = Telerik.Web.UI;
  $T.RadWindow.prototype._createUI = function () {
      //Dynamic rendering of the window 
      //console.log('1');
      if (!this._popupElement) {

          //console.log('2');
          var windowID = this.get_id();
          var wrapperID = 'RadWindowWrapper_' + windowID;
          var isRightToLeft = this._isWindowRightToLeft();
          var rootDiv = document.createElement('div');
          rootDiv.id = wrapperID;
          rootDiv.className = this._getFullSkinName();
          var cssClass = this.get_cssClass(); //get CssClass property value 
          if (cssClass) Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(rootDiv, cssClass);
          if (isRightToLeft) {
              Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(rootDiv, "RadWindow_rtl");
          }
          if (!this._visibleTitlebar) {
              Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(rootDiv, 'rwNoTitleBar');
          }
          rootDiv.style.width = this._width;
          rootDiv.style.height = this._height;
          rootDiv.setAttribute('unselectable', 'on');
          this._popupElement = rootDiv;
          var tableElement = document.createElement('table');
          tableElement.cellSpacing = 0;
          tableElement.cellPadding = 0;
          //set the size through additional CSSClass to prevent inheritance when content template is used 
          Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(tableElement, "rwTable");
          this._tableElement = tableElement;
          //Create the table cells of the window 
          var classNames = [];
          // In the case of direction=rtl, the cells of a table are automatically switched. That is why we need to switch the 
          // order in whick we pass the cells to the ResizeExtender. 
          if (isRightToLeft) {
              classNames = ["rwCorner rwTopRight", "rwTitlebar", "rwCorner rwTopLeft",
              "rwCorner rwBodyRight", "rwWindowContent", "rwCorner rwBodyLeft",
              "rwCorner rwBodyRight", "rwStatusbar", "rwCorner rwBodyLeft",
              "rwCorner rwFooterRight", "rwFooterCenter", "rwCorner rwFooterLeft"];
          }
          else {
              classNames = ["rwCorner rwTopLeft", "rwTitlebar", "rwCorner rwTopRight",
              "rwCorner rwBodyLeft", "rwWindowContent", "rwCorner rwBodyRight",
              "rwCorner rwBodyLeft", "rwStatusbar", "rwCorner rwBodyRight",
              "rwCorner rwFooterLeft", "rwFooterCenter", "rwCorner rwFooterRight"];
          }
          var rowClassNames = ["rwTitleRow", "rwContentRow", "rwStatusbarRow", "rwFooterRow"];
          var index = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
              var row = tableElement.insertRow(-1);
              row.className = rowClassNames[i];
              for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                  var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                  cell.innerHTML = " "; //"<!-- / -->"; 
                  cell.className = classNames[index];
                  index++;
              }
          }
          //Append title element 
          var titleCell = tableElement.rows[0].cells[1];
          titleCell.innerHTML = "";
          this._titleCell = titleCell;
          //Append the top resizer 
          var topResizer = document.createElement('div');
          topResizer.className = "rwTopResize";
          topResizer.innerHTML = "<!-- / -->";
          this._topResizer = topResizer;
          this._titleCell.appendChild(this._topResizer);
          //Titlebar element - holds all other elements in the rwTitlebar 
          var titlebarTable = this._createDefaultTable();
          titlebarTable.className = "rwTitlebarControls";
          this._titlebarElement = titlebarTable;
          this._titleCell.appendChild(this._titlebarElement);
          //Follow 3 rwTitlebar elements - rwIcon(span), title (em), commandbuttons(ul)- the ul is created and maintained by set_behaviros method 
          //Window Icon 
          var windowIcon = this._getTitleIcon();
          var iconCell = this._titlebarElement.rows[0].insertCell(-1);
          iconCell.appendChild(windowIcon);
          //Title text 
          var titleElement = this._getTitleElement();
          var titleCell = this._titlebarElement.rows[0].insertCell(-1);
          titleCell.appendChild(titleElement);
          this.set_title(this._title);
          //Set the behavior [including render available command buttons] 
          var commandCell = this._titlebarElement.rows[0].insertCell(-1);
          //Setting nowrap would not work competely - the UL will still need to be sized 
          commandCell.noWrap = true;
          commandCell.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
          commandCell.appendChild(this._getTitleCommandButtonsHolder());
          //this.set_behaviors(this._behaviors); 
          //Configure content cell 
          var contentCell = tableElement.rows[1].cells[1];
          contentCell.vAlign = "top";
          contentCell.innerHTML = ""; //Clear all existing content 
          this._contentCell = contentCell;
          if (!(this._dockMode || this._isPredefined)) {
              //add additional CSSClass to fix problem with background for some skins, e.g Black when not dockMode 
              Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(this._contentCell, "rwExternalContent");
          }
          if (this._enableShadow && !$telerik.isIE6) {
              //add additional CSSClass to show shadow if enabled 
              this._setShadowCSSClass(true);
          }
          //Name should match the server ID property! It is needed so that default browser 'target' mechanism works! 
          var name = this.get_name();
          //Create rwStatusbar 
          var stastusbarTable = this._createDefaultTable();
          stastusbarTable.style.width = "100%";
          this._statusCell = tableElement.rows[2].cells[1];
          this._statusCell.innerHTML = "";
          this._statusCell.appendChild(stastusbarTable);
          //Create rwStatusbar message cell and rwStatusbar resizer 
          if (isRightToLeft) {
              this._createStatusbarResizer(stastusbarTable);
              this._createStatusbarMessageCell(stastusbarTable);
          }
          else {
              this._createStatusbarMessageCell(stastusbarTable);
              this._createStatusbarResizer(stastusbarTable);
          }
          //Add the wrapper table to the popup element 
          this._popupElement.appendChild(this._tableElement);
          //Add popup to the document 
          this._popupElement.style.display = 'none';
          this._popupElement.style.position = 'absolute';
          this._addWindowToDocument();
          //Add rwTitlebar event handlers 
          this._registerTitlebarHandlers(true);
          //Show/hide titlebars - it needs to be done here AND ins _show. Here - because a window can be shown with some animation. In _show - because the setting might be changed dynamically later using the API 
          this.set_visibleTitlebar(this._visibleTitlebar);
          this.set_visibleStatusbar(this._visibleStatusbar);
          //if in dock mode, do not create the IFRAME at all (removing it later causes memmory leaks) 
          //create a DIV element with the content instead and set it as a content element 
          if (this._dockMode) {
              var contentElement = $get(this.get_id() + "_C");
              if (contentElement && contentElement.innerHTML) {
                  contentElement.style.overflow = "auto";
                  contentElement.style.border = "0px";
                  this.set_contentElement(contentElement);
                  this.setWidthDockMode(this.get_width());
                  this.setHeightDockMode(this.get_height());
              }
          }
          else {
              //Create content IFRAME. Due to a bug in IE regarding setting the name attribute, the following ugly code needs to be used 
              //console.log('IE9.0');
              var childFrame = ($telerik.isIE && !$telerik.isIE9) ?
              document.createElement("<iframe name='" + name + "'>") :
              document.createElement("iframe");
              childFrame.name = name;
              childFrame.src = "javascript:'<html></html>';";
              childFrame.style.width = "100%";
              childFrame.style.height = "100%";
              childFrame.style.border = "0px"; //set to 0 
              childFrame.frameBorder = "0";
              //Only under IE8 it is necessary to set display = "block" for the IFRAME - otherwise it will not occupy 100% of its parent element 
              if ($telerik.isIE8) {
                  childFrame.style.display = "block";
              }
              this._iframe = childFrame;
              this._contentCell.appendChild(this._iframe);
          }
          if (!this._dockMode) {
              //Create a back reference to parent RadWindow 
              this._createBackReference();
          }
      }
      this._updateOpacity();
      //Create the popup if it has not been created 
      if (!this._popupBehavior) {
          //Set behaviors (move, resize,etc etc) - do it here, so that the IFRAME is created and can be passed to be skipped 
          //should be done only once! 
          this.set_behaviors(this._behaviors);
          this._popupBehavior = $create(Telerik.Web.PopupBehavior, {
              'id': (new Date() - 100)//set a unique id 
              + 'PopupBehavior', 'parentElement': null, 'overlay': this._overlay, 'keepInScreenBounds': this._keepInScreenBounds
          }, null, null, this._popupElement);
      }
  };
```

in the exact page and also included 
    jquery-2.1.4.min.js, 
    jquery-1.8.2.js, 
    jquery-1.8.2.intellisence.js, 
    jquery-1.8.2.min.js

but still the error pops up...Please can anyone tell me how to go about resolving this. Thanks.

[image: ScriptResource.axd runtime error]

Comment: that should only execute in IE<9, what browser is giving you trouble?

Comment: ...I am having trouble with browsers IE9, IE10 and Edge...only IE8 and IE7 work without any errors...it seems the custom jquery i added seems to have no effect as its suppose to make it work for all browsers from IE9 and above.

Comment: in 9 and 10 $telerik.isIE should be false, if it's not, then you should clobber the value yourself to stop the legacy code from executing in "newer" browsers.

Comment: ..when you say clobber the value...do you mean comment out the custom code...?...and I don't have access to the original telerik code which is generated from in the ScriptResource.axd file at runtime...or I would have hard coded a solution...

Comment: you don't need access to the code, just say `$telerik.isIE=false;` in IE9+10, which you can figure out how to detect.

Comment: I added this :
  {  function pageLoad() {
          alert('you scallywag');
            if ($.browser.version == '9.0') {
                $telerik.isIE = false;
            }
        }   }
but the error still persist...

Comment: changed it to:


 onPageLoad();
        function onPageLoad()
        {

        if ($.browser.version == '9.0') {
            alert('9');
            $telerik.isIE=false;
        }
        };

still the error remains

Comment: you probably have to do it before load, but it should be able to run inline right after the telerik lib since it doesn't need the dom at all...

Comment: I did what you said and it kind of works...I will explain...there is a portion of the ScriptResource code that references $telerik.isIE see below
else{var l=$telerik.getFirstChildByTagName(r,"div",0);
l.style.width="1px";
l.style.height="1px";

and that portion throws an error since its been set to false and as a result some css of the grid doesn't render well...i.e displays the page partially...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90541/discussion-between-user3323429-and-dandavis).

Comment: well, i'm afraid i'm out of ideas. if it needs it sometimes and not others, i'm not sure how to fix it without forking telerik, which is probably a big complicated en devour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upgrade to the latest version**. Yours is prior to 2011 and does not know about IE9, so the checks are not sufficient. IE9 has a breaking change in the way iframe elements are created with JS, so the old code cannot work as-is.

Here is a thread that provides a function override that MAY help you, but upgrade is the way to go: http://www.telerik.com/forums/problem-opening-radwindow-serverside

Comment: ...yes thanks Rdmptn....I had to force compatibility on the page to IE8...as updating the telerik was not an option and the provided custom code on that page was the precise cause of the initial error...

Comment: That's one reason why such overrides are not a good idea to have in production :) Glad to hear you have a solution for your case.